# Create a temporary file from stream object in c#

Tags: c#, stream, idisposable, using

Given a stream object which contains an xlsx file, I want to save it as a temporary file and delete it when not using the file anymore.

I thought of creating a `class` that implementing `IDisposable` and using it with the `using` code block in order to delete the temp file at the end.

Any idea of how to save the stream to a temp file and delete it on the end of use?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use the [TempFileCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.tempfilecollection.aspx) class:

```
using (var tempFiles = new TempFileCollection())
{
    string file = tempFiles.AddExtension("xlsx");
    // do something with the file here 
}
```

What's nice about this is that even if an exception is thrown the temporary file is guaranteed to be removed thanks to the `using` block. By default this will generate the file into the temporary folder configured on the system but you could also specify a custom folder when invoking the `TempFileCollection` constructor.

Answer (score 13):

You can get a temporary file name with `Path.GetTempFileName()`, create a `FileStream` to write to it and use `Stream.CopyTo` to copy all data from your input stream into the text file:

```
var stream = /* your stream */
var fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

try
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(fs);
    }

    // Do whatever you want with the file here
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Another approach here would be:

```
string fileName = "file.xslx";
int bufferSize = 4096;

var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName, bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions.DeleteOnClose)

// now use that fileStream to save the xslx stream
```

This way the file will get removed after closing.

#### Edit:

If you don't need the stream to live too long (eg: only a single write operation or a single loop to write...), you can, as suggested, wrap this stream into a using block. With that you won't have to dispose it manually.

Code would be like:

```
string fileName = "file.xslx";
int bufferSize = 4096;

using(var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName, bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
{
    // now use that fileStream to save the xslx stream
}
```

Comment: +1, could you wrap it in a `using` block. Certainly the best answer so far.

Comment: This is the way to do it when you need to have a longer lifetime than can be expressed with a using block.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get a random temporary file name w/ path:
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

// Open a FileStream to write to the file:
using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(tempFile)) { ... }

// Delete the file when you're done:
File.Delete(tempFile);
```

EDIT:

Sorry, maybe it's just me, but I could have sworn that when you initially posted the question you didn't have all that detail about a class implementing IDisposable, etc... anyways, I'm not really sure what you're asking in your (edited?) question. But this question: `Any idea of how to save the stream to temp file and delete it on the end of use?` is pretty straight-forward. Any number of google results will come back for ".NET C# Stream to File" or such.

Answer (score 0):

I just suggest for creating file use `Path.GetTempFileName()`. but others depends on your usage senario, for example if you want to create it in your temp creator class and use it just there, it's good to use `using` keyword.